# Método onResume está desfazendo o SharedPreferences de um CheckBox

Tags: java, android

Acontece que eu quero deixar o **CheckBox** salvo de acordo o usuário marque ou não.
Daí eu chamei um método para fazer a checagem de internet caso o **CheckBox** esteja marcado, e logo em seguida o **CheckBox** foi mencionado no **onResume** para ser atualizado principalmente a checagem de internet caso o usuário saia e retorne a aplicação, só que quando mencionado o **onResume** desfaz a opção marcada, veja só:

```
checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkNetwork);
        checkBox.setChecked(getFromSP("checkBox"));
        checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

        checkBox2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkAlertDownload);
        checkBox2.setChecked(getFromSP("checkBox22"));
        checkBox2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

        checkBox3 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkAutoInstall);
        checkBox3.setChecked(getFromSP("checkBox33"));
        checkBox3.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

...

    private boolean getFromSP(String key) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = getApplicationContext
                ().getSharedPreferences("PROJECT_NAME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return preferences.getBoolean(key, false);
    }

    private void saveInSp(String key, boolean value) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = getApplicationContext
                ().getSharedPreferences("PROJECT_NAME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(key, value);
        editor.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean
            isChecked) {
        switch (buttonView.getId()) {
            case R.id.checkNetwork:
                saveInSp("checkBox", isChecked);
                checkConnection();
                break;
            case R.id.checkAlertDownload:
                saveInSp("checkBox22", isChecked);
                break;
            case R.id.checkAutoInstall:
                saveInSp("checkBox33", isChecked);
                break;
        }
    }

    private void checkConnection(){
        boolean isConnected = myNet.isConnected();
        showSnackBar(isConnected);
    }

    private void showSnackBar(boolean isConnected){
        String message;
        int color;
        if (isConnected) {
            message = "Good! Connected to internet";
            color = Color.WHITE;
        } else {
            message = "Sorry! Not connected to internet";
            color = Color.RED;
        }

        Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        checkBox.setChecked(getFromSP("Key");
        MyApplication.getInstance().setConnectivityListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNetworkConnectionChanged(boolean isConnected){
        showSnackBar(isConnected);
    }
}
```

Creio que é porque no **onResume** está chamando o método **getFromSP**, onde está retornando **false** - Nenhuma opção marcada, caso eu mude para **true** - O **CheckBox** mencionado no **onResume** fica sempre marcado.
Alguém pode me ajudar? Tô quebrando a cabeça já faz tempo com isso.
Muito obrigado!

Comment: No onResume vc usa o código 'checkBox.setChecked(getFromSP("Key");' mas você não salva nada com "Key". Você deve usar a mesma chave (key) que você usou para salvar o boolean. No seu exemplo você salva apenas com as chaves "checkBox", "checkBox22" e "checkBox33".

Comment: E o ideal seria você criar uma constante na sua classe para definir essas chaves e não ficar passando uma string qualquer diretamente. ;)